# tty.js does not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, tty

I installed tty.js: `$ npm install -g tty.js`
Then I start it: `$ tty.js`

When I call http://example.com:8080/ I can't open a terminal and http://example.com:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js returns a http error 404.

I tried with node 0.6.19.

I posted in [github](https://github.com/chjj/tty.js/issues/32) but maybe someone from stackoverflow can help :)

Comment: I think your question if too vague.

Answer (score 2):

You should not be using "example.com", which is an external domain, but your own machine. Try replacing it with localhost, or even 127.0.0.1, like so:

```
http://localhost:8080
```